# Unable to install Ant on ubuntu

Tags: ant

Unable to install Ant on ubunut getting below error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: You apparently are using an old and unsupported Java version. class version 52 is Java 8, so you need to install Java 8 to run Ant

Comment: Installed java version as below


openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: What does `java -version` give you?